# Magento2 - Database transactions inside service layer

Tags: dependency-injection, magento2

How make database transactions inside service layer on magento2?

I need use transaction on service layer to expose through webservices.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction support is in `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface` implementation (`\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql`). You can get this object from `\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection` object using DI:

```
/** @var  \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface */
protected $_conn;
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection */
protected $_resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_conn = $resource->getConnection(); // get default connection
}
```

then you can use database transaction for the connection:

```
    try {
        $this->_conn->beginTransaction();
        // ...
        $this->_conn->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_conn->rollBack();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear but you should **not** implement database transaction inside the web service class.

Use the _Repository classes, inject into it's contructor the Resource Model class which contain the code for persisting data into the database.

Example from core Magento: saving a customer group via web service API

```
<route url="/V1/customerGroups/:id" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Customer::group"/>
        </resources>
</route>
```